# Get plugins (like Multiverse) in a normal Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I've set up a Minecraft server using the minecraft_server_1.12.2.jar file that can be found on the Minecraft website. I want to be able to have multiple worlds and the ability to switch between them in-game, so players of my server can have dedicated worlds for each minigame.

Is there a way to do this? I know about the plugin Multiverse, so is there a way to get this plugin with the normal Minecraft server jar file? Or will I have to download Bukkit and start a new server?

Comment: While this looks like a duplicate, there are answers that appear to be worth keeping. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @bearb001 Questions closed as duplicates are not automatically deleted, so it's fine to do so.  The answers would be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use plugins with an unmodified server.

You will have to download one of the alternative servers.

You will not have to start over though.  You can continue to use the same world files.

---

I strongly recommend a full back up copy of the current setup before doing any of this.  Especially the world folder.

Go download [bukkit](https://bukkit.org/), [spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/), or [paper spigot](https://aquifermc.org/).  Make sure to get the latest build for the version you play.

You will put the new server jar in the main folder.  You can leave the vanilla server file in the same folder if you like.  You will then have to change the starting procedure to use the new server jar file.  Start the server fully, then stop it.

This may split the world into 3 world folders.  Folder names starting with the world name and ending with "*_nether*" and "*_the_end*."  This is normal.

This will also give you a new folder named "*plugins*".   Add the plugin jar files to this new folder.  With most plugins, you will want to start the server and stop it again.  This will create configuration files for your plugins which you can modify so the plugin will run how you want.  In the plugins folder, new folders will be created, which are generally named the plugin name.  Inside those folders, you will find the configuration files.  I recommend using the documentation on the plugin's website to learn how to configure each plugin.

Multiverse, in particular, can be quite complicated to setup.  [Here is the wiki](https://github.com/Multiverse/Multiverse-Core/wiki) for Multiverse 2.

Answer (score 0):

No, Vanilla Minecraft can't load mods.

But you should be able to just copy the world to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin are not supported on vanilla servers.

Bukkit, Spigot, Paper are custom made server that have an API that allows plugins to interract with the server.

as explained [in the spigot Wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/about-spigot/):

> It is a modified Minecraft server based on CraftBukkit which provides additional performance optimizations, configuration options and features, whilst still remaining compatible with all existing plugins and consistent with Vanilla Minecraft game mechanics.

There are many tutorials on how to setup a [bukkit](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Setting_up_a_server) or [spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-installation/) server. 
I personnaly prefer spigot for performances.